# How to set the sharing rights of a folder in Plone?

Tags: python, permissions, plone, zope

I want to set sharing rights of many folders by using a Python script in a Plone site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to look at the [`AccessControl/rolemanager.py`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/AccessControl/blob/master/src/AccessControl/rolemanager.py) module for details; the sharing tab in Plone is a friendly wrapper around that API.

To add roles for a given userid, call [`manage_addLocalRoles`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/AccessControl/blob/master/src/AccessControl/rolemanager.py#L323-L336):

```
context.manage_addLocalRoles('userid', ('Role1', 'Role2',))
```

The other two important methods are `manage_setLocalRoles(userid, roles)` (replace the current set of roles completely) and `manage_delLocalRoles(userid)` (delete all roles). `get_local_roles_for_userid(userid)` could be handy too, to see what local roles are already defined.

You want to reindex security information after such changes:

```
context.reindexObjectSecurity()
```

Comment: and where to set the permissions on a specific folder, like can read, can write etc.

Comment: This are roles. "Can Read" is the Reader Role.