# How to set the sharing rights of a folder in Plone using a python script?

Tags: python, permissions, plone

This question has been asked before ([How to set the sharing rights of a folder in Plone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763150/how-to-set-the-sharing-rights-of-a-folder-in-plone)), but it wasn't really answered --- at least from what I can tell.

I want to set the sharing rights of a given folder (or form folder) using a Python script in a Plone 4 site. For example, if Bob has the ability to view the folder "Images", then the script will remove his ability to view "Images". This can be done manually using the "Sharing" tab on the folder, and I'm trying to work out how to do the same thing using a script without changing Bob's roles. (I've looked at rolemanager.py and I can't find anything there that I can use)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't create a duplicate question if a previous question on the same subject has not yet been answered. My answer there is exactly what I'd give you here.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have sufficient reputation to comment on your answer. Chenxiong Qi asked you a follow-up (which I take to be his original question, but I could be wrong, since your answer has several up votes).

Comment: His original question was about the *sharing* tab, which only handles roles. The 'read', 'write', etc. headers in the sharing tab correspond to specific local roles.

Comment: If you have a different question from that, then you may want to update this post to differentiate the issue. You do almost always want to use roles, however. Permissions apply to roles, users are given permissions *via* roles. So you end up adding or removing local roles almost exclusively. Assigning specific permissions to roles is an application configuration task done rarely.

Comment: Thanks Martjin. I worked out what my problem was: I didn't realise local roles regulated the permissions. After using your solution, I now have a new problem regarding a permissions problem when a non-admin user causes the script to run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923149/python-script-to-hide-ploneformgen-form-after-user-has-filled-it-out-for-plone