# Plone does not fully recognize manage_setLocalRoles changes

Tags: permissions, plone, roles

I have a script that is using manage_setLocalRoles to assign a specific role to certain users specified. See below for snippet

```
context.manage_setLocalRoles(username, (‘Editor’, ‘Reviewer’))
context.reindexObjectSecurity()
```

After that script runs, you can go to the Sharing tab of the page and see the user specified with `Reviewer` and `Editor` checked. However, that user does not have any of the rights that go with those roles.

For testing, I have performed the following checks

- `context.getMyRolesInContext()` does not return any of the roles set above.
- `context.get_local_roles_for_userid(username)` only displays the roles set above, and not any global roles set (when testing as site manager and the like).
- `context.portal_membership.checkPermission(“Modify portal content”)` returns a `False`.

With `Editor` role I should have `Modify portal content` permission. I did verify in the workflow of the content type to make sure the roles are set correctly for the permissions in each state. And as a double check, I ran this script on the content.

```
username = context.getCurrentUserName()
roles = context.rolesOfPermission('Modify portal content')
member = context.portal_membership.getMemberById(username)
for role in roles:
    if role['selected']!='':
        print role['name']
        print member.has_role(role['name'], context)

return printed
```

This was my result:

```
Editor
0
Manager
1
Reviewer
0
Site Administrator
0
```

Those results are from my site manager role, but after I ran the manage_setLocalRoles on my user to add `Editor` and `Reviewer`.

Any thoughts as to why the roles aren’t recognized everywhere? Or am I using the wrong process for what I am trying to accomplish?

**NOTE** - I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763150/how-to-set-the-sharing-rights-of-a-folder-in-plone/7763989#7763989) answer, and as my code reflects I am already doing what it suggests.

**EDIT**

Adding versions per comment. We have quite a few add-ons, but none of them seem like they would be related. Mostly jQuery integrations, and types like PFG, True Gallery, FullCalendar. We are using a custom theme and all custom content types and workflows. Excluding the content type I am currently creating for this project both the theme and all other content types were created before I got here. The types are Archetypes extensions.

- OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
- Plone - 4.3.2
- Products.ATContentTypes - 2.1.13
- AccessControl - 3.0.8

Comment: Go to manage_access on your `context` and enter the user id. You should see the roles (of the user in this context) with the assigned permissions.

Comment: What does you see on manage_access?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Couldn't access it this weekend. Looking at `manage_access` all permissions look correct for each role. Entering the username though still shows I only have `Authenticated` and `Manager` roles (both in global and in context).

Comment: By the way, if I go to the Sharing tab I see the correct roles (Editor, Reviewer) checked for that user. If I `save` without changing anything the user is then granted the permissions for those roles.

Comment: Ufff... There must be something wring with either indexing, setting local roles, or transactions. Can you tell us more about your environment? Plone Version, AddOns?

Comment: Added info in the post as an edit. I don't know if I listed everything I should have, but it seemed like a long list to provide if it isn't necessary.

Comment: UGH! Ok, sorry for wasting your time. I just figured it out. It boiled down to case sensitivity. Our users are fed from Active Directory, and some are all caps and the rest are all lower. Somehow there was a misconnect somewhere and the set roles command was always using all lower. I fixed, and will post the details. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem boiled down to case sensitivity. Our users are fed from an Active Directory plugin. Some of the usernames are all caps, and others are all lower. Somehow the username being used in my set roles command were always lowercase. As a result, `user` was getting the roles, when it should have been `USER`.

My Solution was to first get the actual member from `portal_membership`, then grab the username from the member.

```
pm = getToolByName(self, 'portal_membership')
user = pm.getMemberById(username)
self.manage_setLocalRoles(member.getUserName(), ('Reviewer', 'Editor'))
self.reindexObjectSecurity()
```

Apparently `getMemberById()` is not case sensitive, and it returns the correct username in the correct case. So I was just missing that extra check/filter.